# Distplot with custom x and y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a distribution plot for cab bookings count in Python. I have the data of the booking counts for each hour. But when I plot it by using Seaborn. Its giving the counts on x axis.

My expected plot is the timings on x axis and y axis should have the counts of it.
The column names are time and Total Bookings.

I got a graph using scatter plot but I want similar graph with pdf.
Below is my code for scatter plot but I need for distplot.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(9,7))

plt.scatter(df_train_x['time'],df_train_x['Total Bookings'])
plt.xticks(range(24))
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Total Bookings')
```

[image]

Please help me in plotting this graph. Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the relevant code? Or a [mcve] which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Basically What I want is a bi variant dist plot. Time on x axis and Total booking on y axis. I am not able to put a image in the post. What I am getting now is this: https://imgur.com/a/3UNbWhu. I want time wise distribution of Total Bookings.

Comment: The current output you’re getting is useful - thank you for adding it - but really we need to see the relevant code (and some data) in order to properly answer your question. Can you supply the relevant code or an [mcve] and some of the data you are using?

Comment: I have included code of scatter plot and its code. But I want a pdf curve for it. Please help me with it.